# Hide/show div using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

which is initially hidden, on button click i want to show table rows which in turn get data from WCF service. I am new to angular so i m not able to show the table on button click. it flickers and goes away.

```
.html snippet
       <div data-ng-hide="vm1.organizationNumber!=0 && !loading">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover  table-striped">
                                <thead>

                                    <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                        <th>Organization #</th>
                                        <th>Contract #</th>
                                        <th>Plan #</th>
                                        <th>Company Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{vm1.organization}}</td>
                                    <td>{{vm1.number}}</td>
                                    <td>{{vm1.PlanName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{vm1.EmployerName}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: There is no button in the html and we have no idea what events are bound to it or how your variables in ng-hide are changed. Suggest you remove some of the table html from question and show more logic code and button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example: the "Switch" button will toggle a boolean variable called `switch`, and the div will be hidden or shown based on the value of that variable.

```
<button ng-click="switch = !switch">switch</button>

<div ng-hide="switch"></div>
```

Comment: `ng-Class` depending on model  is good way too. Use animation class `appear`-`disapear` so that it will be nicer for little efforts thanks to angular JS.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what this will actually do, to make this a more useful answer for the community?